# How can you create an ActiveRecord collection from two separate tables without STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relational-database, ruby-on-rails-5

We have two models that belong to company: customer and vendor invoices. Currently they have their own index pages; generating a collection for pagination/sorting on these pages is as easy as `current_company.customer_invoices`.

```
class CustomerInvoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end

class VendorInvoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :customer_invoices, -> { order(due_date: :desc) }
  has_many :vendor_invoices, -> { order(due_date: :desc) }
end
```

We now need to make a shared index page that will paginate and sort both kinds of invoices. STI seems like the obvious solution, but since they are functionally VERY different, and have **minimal intersection** in their schema columns, it strikes us as a bad use case. Is there any other option besides loading all of the records and sorting/paginating them in memory?

```
class Company
  def invoices
    (customer_invoices + vendor_invoices)
  end
end

class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @invoices = current_company
                  .invoices
                  .sort_by(&:due_date)
                  .page(params[:whaveter_page])
  end
end
```

As the number of invoices grows this will have super terrible memory performance :( .

Answer (score 2):

To give you a best answer, one would need to know about the structure of your database, use cases etc.

But here are two approaches that you can consider:

1. Create separate table that will store data for both models. Such table should only contain columns required for filtering, sorting and data displayed on the combined list. and of course references to original rows in respectable tables. With such table it is pretty straightforward, you just query this table. Major disadvantage is that now you need to write to two tables when creating or updating invoice. But generating combined index will be super-fast. Technically you can move all the indexes to this table only and do other database optimizations.
2. You can use `UNION` statement and combine results from both tables into one. You need to select similar columns from both tables with same types. It will be slower than the first solution, but the advantage is that you don't have to maintain additional table. It will be created on demand. Writing union statement with active record may be a little bit challenging

Comment: Another way could be to create the view that holds common columns and references to original records resembling the STI. The database will do the union, and ActiveRecord queries would be easier. Also no need to update two tables on writes.